# Foundation 4 Section (accordion) Events

Tags: events, accordion, zurb-foundation

I have an application with an accordion.  The accordion's section .content is pulled from a server, generated dynamically and can be rather large.  Therefore it would be best to load the   content only when the user opens the section.  My though is that the best way to do this would be binding to a section open event, display a loading icon while fetching the content, then displaying that content.

However, I'm having great difficulty binding to the open event.  There does not seem to be a great deal of documentation on the new Foundation 4 section/tabs/accordion.  What I did see may have been for foundation 3.  It said open/opened/close/closed events should be sent, but they do not seem to be thrown.

The only event I seem able to bind to is "click."  Which would work, except the accordion frequently loads with the first section already open.  I could run `myExampleDynamicLoader($('section.active'))` on document ready, but it seems like there should be a less hackish way.

I created a jsFiddle to show what I'm talking about http://jsfiddle.net/HurricaneJamesEsq/6sGGD/14/

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

After reading through the foundation.section.js source, it is pretty clear that sections do not trigger any events.  A pull request was added, but in the mean time it looks like this can only be done via 'click' events.